# mySql statement

Tags: mysql

I have a sql statement where I want to get all the entry with the category of "Game" but do not want to retrieve the record with the code of "A00001".

Below is my sql code but there is an error in the where clause.

```
 $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM productItem WHERE productName = '$name' AND skuCode != '$mySKU';";
```

Comment: And the exact error is? You can remove the first `;` too.

Comment: Key points: 1) What's the *generated* SQL code as seen by MySQL 2) What's the error message. Don't ignore the information you get.

Comment: post the error message...

Answer (score 1):

```
$mySKU = 'A00001';
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM productItem WHERE productName = '$name' AND skuCode != '$mySKU'";
```

You have an extra `;` lurking somewhere in there. Be sure to sanitize `$mySKU` if it is user input and use `prepared` statements.

**update**:
 Using PDO:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM productItem WHERE productName = :name AND skuCode != :mySKU");
if ($stmt->execute(array('name' => $name, "mySKU" => $mySKU))) {
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); //if you are sure there are records
```

Comment: I think the error we have seen should be pointed out. Assume OP doesn't know how to copy and paste error. I don't get the downvote. :|

Comment: The answer is not useful until we hear back from the OP.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM productItem WHERE productName = '$name' AND skuCode <> '$mySKU';";
```

Not equal statement is <>
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal

Comment: != is a valid operator. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html